# Modem Cable also connects to a.c. power supply

Tags: networking, router

My ISP provided me with a small "modem" attached to the wall near my computer desk.  A cable runs from there to my router which sits on my desk.  Just before this cable enters my router at the WAN port, it has a connection to another wire which runs to an a.c. power source and is plugged into a normal a.c. receptacle.  So the power source is providing power to "what ?"    The router has its own separate power source !  If I unplug the questionable power source I have no internet connection.   Can someone explain what is happening - why is that power source required ?

Wayne

Comment: Who is your isp?

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the modem, and the cable to the router showing the extra connection? Upload your image to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get a link you can share. [Edit] your question to include this link and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you.

Comment: what kind of internet connection is this? DSL, Cable, something else?

Comment: Does your "modem" have a make and model number?

Comment: *"So the power source is providing power to "what ?""* -- Apparently what you call the *"modem"*.

Comment: "So the power source is providing power to "what ?" - Your modem.  Your router is your own hardware, its not required, for your ISP to serve you internet.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a Power over Ethernet adapter.  I have seen them used to power a dish receiver that is connected outdoors, but I can't be sure from your description.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering instead of commenting as my reply is too long.  My ISP is a small local company (MCSNET) which has several towers in our part of Alberta.  The closest tower is about 1 mile away, sends a signal  to a "radio" attached to the receiver dish mounted on the roof of my house.   A cable then runs from the dish to a "modem" (that's what I've been calling it anyway) which is mounted on the inside wall near my computer.  It may be just a "connection box" .  It is plastic about 3 inches square X 1 inch thick and has no markings on it.  I don't want to take it apart to look inside unless it was really necessary.   About 4 inches before the cable enters the router WAN port, there is a small connector (approx. a 1 inch cube).  This is where the wire from the power source connects to the main cable.  The connector has two arrows showing "to the computer" and "to the radio".   And having read the other replies it seems obvious now that the power is going back to the "radio" attached to the dish.  I was not aware that power was required for that - in fact I had not seen those two arrows until after I asked my question on the forum.    I thank you all for your responses and particularly "heavyd"  whose reply hit the mark I think.

Answer (score 0):

It is a POE adapter, short for Power Over Ethernet.
It makes your ethernet cable (the one with the clip) able to power POE devices, things such as routers and modems.
You could try to un-plug your small modem to see if it stays powered on with the POE cable connected.

If your modem stays on, it means it is POE enabled and is able to use the power provided through the ethernet cable and little adapter connected to said cable.

I hope i answered your question!